# Android Jump&Run - Random map generation

Tags: android, maps, random

I'm pretty new to game development but I work on an android app.
It's a 2D Jump and Run game.

I do it in Eclipse and the map is readed out of a txt file right now.
But I want to do a Jump and run game, where the player must jump over holes in the ground.
Theses holes should be created randomly. So I want an infinite map, which is created randomly.
Can somebody give me tips how to begin with this? How can I do a randomly generated map?
I don't want the full code or something else, just a little tip how to start because I don't know how I can do this randomly generating.

Thanks in advance! Hope u know, what I mean!

Comment: Unfortunately questions like this are just too broad for the site. You should try jumping in and implementing something, then ask specific questions about the problems you encounter along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd define a minimal interval between two holes (I assume your map is tiled so let's say this interval is 2 tiles), then every time a new tile enters the screen, if there wasn't a hole for the previously defined interval, generate a random number to know if the new tile will be a hole.